# ajax requested json not populating flot chart

Tags: jquery, json, flot

I have created a php to return scores from the db through json encode. Flot just doesnt seem to want them. Theres no errors being returned in firebug. So i am stuck. All i get is a blank chart-

[image]

The code..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        var options = {
             bars: {
                show: true
            }
        }

        $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);

        var iteration = 0;

        function fetchData() {

            ++iteration;

            function onDataReceived(series) {

                data = [ series ];

                $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/charts/data",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onDataReceived
            });

            if (iteration < 5) {
                setTimeout(fetchData, 10000);
            } else {
                data = [];
                alreadyFetched = {};
            }
        }
        fetchData();
        setTimeout(fetchData, 10000);



    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h2>AJAX</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The php that returns the data is

```
    $data = array(array('1999',3.0),array('2000',3.9),array('2001',2.0),array('2002',1.2)); 
    $array = array('label' => 'Scores','data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode(array($array));
```

And the return Json is

```
[{"label":"Scores","data":[["1999",3],["2000",3.9],["2001",2],["2002",1.2]]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the offending line of code:

```
data = [ series ]; // do not wrap in another array
```

You JSON is already in the dataformat flot wants.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/yd6LU/).